# Haven't found SD Card folder on Android Emulator (Virtual device)?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

Actually I am trying to create a SD Card space on my Android Emulator and I'm succeed into it. But the problem is that the folder of MyFile, is not available on Android Virtual device when i look for it on a click of a Apps option. And also not showing the space available when I look into the settings --> Storage.

But when i transferred one of Application into the sd card it shows the  Total space and available space in sd card but still not able to found the folder of SD card memory.

How am I found it help me out please......

Thanks in Advance For any help or suggestion...............

Comment: can view from DDMS 'll not wrok here?

Comment: it is available in mnt folder! But the application I have transferred into it not there......

Answer (score 3):

Go to DDMS->File Explorer->mnt->sd card

Comment: I have found it on DDMS's File explorer, But here I'm asking is how to find on Virtual device not on Eclipse's DDMS window.....

Answer (score 1):

Click on DDMS, select your Emulator from devices. From FileExplorer select mnt/sdcard. This is the path for the emulator's SDCard. But to look for installed application follow Riteeka's answer.

Comment: I have found it on DDMS's File explorer, But here I'm asking is how to find on Virtual device not on Eclipse's DDMS window..... By which I can able to see my files into sd card memory on emulator device. I have a idea how to look for file of sdcard through DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no folder named MyFile in emulator, and You can browse sdcard contents in FileExplorer. The path following sdcard is FileExplorer -> Data/Data/mnt/sdcard.

I think this might help you!!

Comment: I have found it on DDMS's File explorer, But here I'm asking is how to find on Virtual device not on Eclipse's DDMS window..... By which I can able to see my files into sd card memory on emulator device. I have a idea how to look for file of sdcard through DDMS.